# How can I hide the parent folder name in the URL?

Tags: html, wordpress, apache, url

I'm trying to hide the parent folder name in the URL. I have the address `www.sitename.com/folderparent/folderchild/` and I want it to be `www.sitename.com/folderchild/`. My Wordpress site is in folderchild.

**How can I achieve this?**

I also have another Wordpress site at `www.sitename.com/parentchild`.

Comment: You already asked this — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932500/how-can-i-hide-the-parent-folder-name-in-the-url — Don't just delete questions and then ask them again.

Comment: It sounds like you just installed Wordpress in the wrong directory. Why not just delete it and start again in the right directory?

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. I can't delete and start again because i'm managing an active website. There isn't a method in .htaccess?

Answer (score -1):

Install the two wordpress in separate directories.

It seems that you are now placing folderchild in folderparent, why don't you directly create two directories on the same level and install wordpress in each one?

If you can give more information we can help you better. Do you need the child directory to be inside the parent?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm managing a start website which was created in the folderparent and properly redirected with .htaccess. Subsequently there was a need to create another site in a different language so we created the new site in a folder inside the folderparent.